When I run a function to try and count the words in a text area, the function does not run
I have a function that counts words in a text area box(written in html), but when I try and run the function, though javascript or html, it does not run. I am new to javascript, so I might be missing something obvious.
I tried using onkeyup in my html file, but it doesnt run the function, and when i try it in my js file, it doesnt run either.  Here is my js:
Here is the code snippet:


let textarea = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount").innerHTML;
textarea.onkeyup = function () {
let words = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount").value;
let count = 0;
let split = words.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
     if (split[i] != "") {
         count += 1;
     }
}
count = document.getElementById("wordcount").value;
}
<p><textarea id="myWordsToCount" onkeyup="textarea()" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea><br>




count = document.getElementById("wordcount").value; should be document.getElementById("wordcount").value = count. Otherwise you don't do anything with count.

Also you don't want the .innerHTML of the <textarea>, you want the element itself.

textarea = function () { 
   
    let words = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount").value;
    let count = 0;
    let split = words.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i] != "") {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
     document.getElementById("wordcount").value = count; // input.value <- count putting the result in inputs value 
}
   // html :
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <p><textarea id="myWordsToCount" onkeyup="textarea()" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea><br>
            <input type="text" id="wordcount">
    </body>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
    </html>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
